# Self-referencing SQL statement

Tags: mysql, expressionengine

Overview: I need to write an custom SQL question in ExpressionEngine.

I have a product table (exp_channel_titles) that is assigned categories (exp_category_posts). In EE categories are grouped (as defined in exp_categories).

Here's what I'm trying to do...

When I'm displaying a particular product (single row), I want to go back to the product table and pull random "suggestions" as based on the categories in a certain category group of the displayed product. Finally, I want to be sure to exclude the displayed product from the suggestions.

My SQL is ok but this is fairly advance in my book. I'm here hoping to get some helps.

Thus far I can get the single row and it's categories from the category group I'm interested in. But now what?

```
  SELECT * 

  FROM exp_channel_titles 

  LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts 

  ON exp_channel_titles.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id

  LEFT JOIN exp_categories

  ON exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id

  WHERE exp_channel_titles.entry_id = "17" AND exp_categories.group_id = "3"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

-- UPDATE -- 
I suppose this is brute force but it works, almost.

```
SELECT *

FROM exp_channel_titles my1

LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts my2

ON  my1.entry_id = my2.entry_id

LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts my3

ON  my1.entry_id = my3.entry_id

LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts my4

ON  my1.entry_id = my4.entry_id

WHERE my3.cat_id = "7" AND my2.cat_id = "2" AND my1.entry_id != "17" AND my4.cat_id IN (

SELECT exp_category_posts.cat_id

FROM exp_category_posts

LEFT JOIN exp_categories ON exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id 

WHERE exp_category_posts.entry_id = '17' AND exp_categories.group_id = '3'
```

)

Since I'm needing to filter by categories from 3 different category groups I do 3 LEFT JOINs. The first two are just focused on a single category (2=published, 7=music), the third could return multiple values from the subquery so I'm using IN. The subquest asked For entry_id = X (in this case 17, which is the main/single product being displayed) what categories from group_id=3 (music) should I be suggesting?

The final question is, since the subquery returned multiple rows, the main select can return dupes. I want a list of unique products. What now? Group by? Order by?

Pardon this nooby question but to be honest Google sucks when it comes to finding answers. There's tons of crap examples, unanswered questions, etc. I'm know the concepts, but my syntax is rusty. Please help a brother out.

If anyone see any easy way to optimize the above, I'll glad listen. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: Not sure if this will work, and it could very likely do with some optimization, but perhaps this will work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ect.*
FROM
    exp_channel_titles ect
    LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts ecp ON ect.entry_id = ecp.entry_id
    LEFT JOIN exp_categories ec ON ecp.cat_id = ec.cat_id
WHERE
    ect.entry_id != '17'
    AND ec.group_id IN (
        SELECT ec.group_id
        FROM 
            exp_channel_titles ect
            LEFT JOIN exp_category_posts ecp ON ect.entry_id = ecp.entry_id
            LEFT JOIN exp_categories ec ON ecp.cat_id = ec.cat_id
        WHERE
            ect.entry_id = '17'
    );
```

Comment: Thx. I'll give this a go. My main issue is syntax. I'm not sure how to do pre-select query. The AND...bit above might be what I'm needing. I'll report back shortly. Thank you.

Comment: I think this might do it. But how do I get the subquery to return multiple rows. Instead of ec.group_id =, how can I say if ec.group_id = is one of these values in this subquery? Thx again

Comment: Change `ec.group_id = (` to `ec.group_id IN (` and remove the `LIMIT 1` in the subquery.....see updated answer.

Comment: Well it wasn't THE answer but you got me in the right direction. I'm in the home stretch. Thanks again. If you know the answer to the de-dupe'ing please serve it up. I'm still hungry :)

Comment: If you are getting duplicate rows, try changing `SELECT ect.*` to `SELECT DISTINCT ect.*`. See updated answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with native EE tags using [related categories mode](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#related-categories-mode). Just make a new channel:entries loop outside of your main product channel:entries tag, or embed it if you have to.

Comment: Thx. But unless I skimmed too fast that isn't going to work. Mainly because it's too broad. I have multiple category groups and when I do the suggestions I need to only consider two of them

Comment: Will these two category groups be dynamic based on the product? Or are you able to hardcode them?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest embedding a template within your channel:entries loop, and passing the current entry_id as an embed parameter.

`{embed="embeds/related_products" entry_id="{entry_id}"}`

Then in your embedded template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" category_group="3|4" entry_id="not {embed:entry_id}" limit="5" orderby="random"}
    // variables here
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Close but the issue is - and pardon me for not saying this sooner (my EE is a bit rusty and drilling down on this by the minute) - I need category='8|15' (from one group) *and* also category='2' (from another group). EE, best can can tell can't do or ( | ) and and (&) in the same category=. e.g. pseudo code category='2 & (8|15)'. I think I'm stuck with the Query module. It seems like a fairly common concept. I'm surprised it's so difficult to find a grab-a-snippet answer.

Comment: If you can make this work using EE tags, your life will be made easier. Otherwise, you need to  write a query that gives you a list of entry IDs (easy enough), but then those need to be piped into the "entry_id" or "fixed_order" parameter of another channel:entries tag.

Comment: Have you tried using both the "category" AND "category_group" parameters to narrow your results down in the way you need?

Comment: @Derek-Houge First, thanks for your input. At least now I know there's another good EE resource here. The EE forums seem to have gotten soft & weak :(  Yes, I'm trying to do this with standard tags. I even tried a SQL statement in to PHP $var into an EE exp:entries loop. It's the categories and the AND + OR that's making that gymnastics tough. Plus my SQL is rusty. I've got a couple more things to try. I'm gonna crack this one. It's my duty :)